# How to lower Count without reducing Capacity in C# List

Tags: c#, list, count, capacity

I have a list that should be completely removed once every frame on an interactive app.

I reserved a capacity to 10.000 items at the beginning to avoid the overhead of adding items one by one.

Then I want to remove all of them. Apparently using Clear() will set Capacity to 0. Does it? How do I keep the capacity then?

Comment: No, use [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,ca7bce81a50b0aeb) Luke.

Comment: @HansPassant or RTFM - ["Capacity remains unchanged"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.clear?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Answer (score 2):

`Clear()` does not reset the capacity:

```cs
var list = new List<int>(500);
list.Add(42);
list.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // 0
Console.WriteLine(list.Capacity); // 500
```

(at least, not on regular .NET Framework / .NET Core). So: just call `Clear()`. If you're using something more exotic, you'll need to be specific about your target framework.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why people downvoted my question. It could happen that I didn't know the sources were open.